# bash ls file with other file in directory

Tags: linux, bash, ls

I want to list 2 files, one in current directory and one in subdirectory.

I have this:

```sh
tree
.
├── file1
└── folder1
    └── file1
```

And I want to do ls to list both file1, how can I do it?
I remember there is something like `ls {file1|folder1/file1}` but I dont remember the syntax and how to use it

Comment: `ls -l file1 folder1/file1` is an explicit way. Or if your filesystem is huge with `file1` scattered all over, you can use `find /start/path -type f -name file1` and it will list all `file1` found below `/start/path`. Here that would be `find . -type f -name file1`

Comment: You may want: `shopt -s globstar; ls **/file1`.

Comment: Questions about using bash as a user, instead of about writing scripts, are better placed at [UNIX.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well I found it,
its [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) (credit to [user:1934428](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934428/user1934428))

just something cool:
to see extended ls feature just see [extended globbing in bash](https://riptutorial.com/bash/example/13126/extended-globbing)

and what I was looking for is this:

```sh
ls {.,*}/file1
```

Comment: Could also be `ls {.,folder1)/file1` using your brace-expansion. Using `'*'` will search all directories -- which if that is what you want -- that's fine.

Comment: BTW: This is not extended globbing. It is brace expansion, together with just normal globbing.